# Entity Framework Data Annotation Globalization

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, data-annotations

A sample that I have copied from another thread.

```
[Display(Name = "Email", ResourceType = typeof(Localization))]
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Localization))]
[Email(ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmailFormatError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Localization))]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Is there a way for me to specify a global ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Localization)?

Because I have to do this so many times (at least 2 or 3 annotation for every single property in every entity object).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are building a web app, then this could be useful: http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/localizing-default-error-messages-in-asp-net-mvc-and-web-form. I have never use it though

Comment: do you have multiple `ErrorMessageResourceType`s?

Comment: You could subclass the attributes that you use, though that would be annoying if you have many.